# Linear Transformation with $F=\mathbb Q$ or $ F=\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Please help with following question:
$V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over a field $F$. A mapping $T : V \to W$satisfies the condition $T(v_1 + v_2) = T(v_1) + T(v_2)$. Is $T$ a linear transformation if $(a): F = Q $

$(b) F = R$ ?

Comment: try to prove "yes" for Q first: T(mv)=mT(v) and T(v/n)=T(v)/n since T(v)=T(nv/n)=nT(v/n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outline: (a) Over the rationals, the answer is yes, $T$ is a linear transformation. We need to prove that for any rational $r$, we have $T(rv)=rT(v)$.

Use the given relation to show that if $p$ is a positive integer, then $T(pv)=pT(v)$. This can be done by induction. Suppose that we know that $T(pv)=pT(v)$. We want to show that $T((p+1)v)=(p+1)T(v)$. This is easy, for 
$$T((p+1)v)=T(pv+v)=T(pv)+T(v)=pT(v)+T(v)=(p+1)T(v).$$

Now show that if $q$ is a positive integer, then $T((1/q)v)=(1/q)T(v)$. Use the fact that $T((q)((1/q)v)=qT((1/q)v)$.

We also need to take care of negative rationals.

(b) Things are very different over the reals. For information, please search under *Hamel Basis*. Look also for information about the Cauchy Functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. One can show (using the Axiom of Choice) that this equation has solutions other than $f(x)=kx$.

Comment: thanks. but how to show T(-v)= -T(v)?

Comment: Use, $T(0+0)=T(0)+T(0)\Rightarrow T(0)=0$ thus $T(0)=T(v-v)=T(v)+T(-v)=0\Rightarrow T(-v)=-T(v)$